# Cargo default build target per workspace members

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have three members in my workspace and I want to comiple the first member with `musl` and other two members with `glibc`. I have created a `.cargo/config` file in the project root folder with `glibc` configs. And created another `.cargo/config` file in the first member folder with `musl` configs. However my first member was not compiled with `musl`. I want to run the first member in an alpine docker container and I am managing docker containers with the second member. How to solve this?